# How to read map in spark3 with java

Tags: spark3

DataSet person = spark.read.textfile(path).map(Person::new,Encoders.bean(Person.class))

when i tried above it will works in spark2.4(scala-2.11) but in spark3.1.1(scala-2.12) it's shows as ambigous for the type DataSet.
And also wherver i use map,filter,mappartitions,flatmap got ambigous/

but by doing type casting will get success for all transformations
spark.read.textfile(path).map((MapFunction<String,Person>)Person::new,Encoders.bean(Person.class))

Is there any other way without typecasting/codechanges

Answer (score 0):

From Migration guide, chapter 'SQL, Datasets and DataFrame':

> In Spark 3.0, Dataset query fails if it contains ambiguous column
> reference that is caused by self join. A typical example: val df1 =
> ...; val df2 = df1.filter(...);, then df1.join(df2, df1("a") >
> df2("a")) returns an empty result which is quite confusing. This is
> because Spark cannot resolve Dataset column references that point to
> tables being self joined, and df1("a") is exactly the same as df2("a")
> in Spark. To restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, you can set
> spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false.

Source https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html